# How can I see full program name in GNOME search bar?

Tags: gnome-shell, search, installed-programs, activities-overview

I've installed a Citrix client on my laptop and when I now search for it, I see this:

[image]

They seem identical, but maybe the title of the programs is different. How can I see the full title of those programs in this search window?